# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar a una página (Local en carpeta) con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito redireccionar a una página local, en carpeta de usuario, sí y solo sí se cumple la condicional, como ven, coloque el atributo **`document.location.assing`**.

Pero el mismo no me redirecciona o hace alguna acción, quedo en la misma página, lo estoy utilizando para verificar un login sin base de datos, simple y llanamente para que si se cumple, redireccione al inicio, caso contrario, se quede en el mismo, pero para verificar que funcionaba le coloqué el alert, la misma está colocada en un "onclick" del botón del login.

Aún soy un poco novato en esto, de igual forma sé que puedo utilizar el **`window.open()`**, pero me abre una nueva pestaña, cosa que no me funciona del todo.

Agradecería la ayuda que me puedan prestar.

```
function validate(){
                    var user = document.getElementById("userneim").value;
                    var password = document.getElementById("pasword").value;

                    if(user == 'User' && password == '123'){
                        document.location.assing('../index.html');
                    }else{
                        alert("Usuario Inválido");
                    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Por ejemplo:

```
var url = "https://www.ejemplo.com";    
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

o Tambien:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

var pagina="http://www.yahoo.com"
function redireccionar() 
{
location.href=pagina
} 
setTimeout ("redireccionar()", 20000);

</script>
```

Comment: De igual manera a ti, me has dado una segunda opcion a tomar en cuenta al momento de colocar el código, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La funcion `window.open()` puede redireccionar en la misma pestaña. El segundo parametro indica adonde debe abrir la pagina. Lo puedes usar asi:

```
window.open("../index.html", "_self");
```

Tambien puede usar la funcion

```
location.href="../index.html";
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, en serio me ha sido de mucha ayuda.